# Why is it repeating the even though the WHILE loop is changed to False

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I can not work out why it keeps repeating the function, even though the condition to change the while loop to false is met. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
confirm=True

def program():
    name=input("What is your name? ")
    country=input("What is your country? ")

    runagain=input("Would you like to run again? Enter no or yes: ")
    if runagain=="no":
        print("Thank You")
        confirm=False
    else:
        print("Rerun")
        confirm=True

while confirm==True:
    program()
```

Comment: `confirm` in the global scope is different from `confirm` in the function. You never change the global variable `confirm`. Anyway, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use global confirm in your method program.

Check this out

```
confirm=True

def program():
    global confirm
    name=input("What is your name? ")
    country=input("What is your country? ")

    runagain=input("Would you like to run again? Enter no or yes: ")
    if runagain=="no":
        print("Thank You")
        confirm=False
    else:
        print("Rerun")
        confirm=True

while confirm:
    program()
```

Using global is a bad sign of writing code.
Instead you remove a lot of code in your code, making it fewer lines.
Refer this

```
def program():
    name=input("What is your name? ")
    country=input("What is your country? ")
    runagain=input("Would you like to run again? Enter no or yes: ")
    if runagain=="no":
        print("Thank You")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Rerun")

while 1:
    program()
```

Comment: `exit()` inside `program()` might solve the dummy example, but it is not robust. What if he wants to do something else after that? It will be much better if `program()` will just return if it succeeded or not.

Comment: I wrote this answer particularly for his code to work.I understand your point

Answer (score 2):

Python is Statically Scoped

http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

```
# This is a global variable
a = 0

if a == 0:
    # This is still a global variable
    b = 1

def my_function(c):
    # this is a local variable
    d = 3
    print(c)
    print(d)

# Now we call the function, passing the value 7 as the first and only parameter
my_function(7)

# a and b still exist
print(a)
print(b)

# c and d don't exist anymore -- these statements will give us name errors!
print(c)
print(d)
```

The global keyword works but may be counterproductive...

> Note that it is usually very bad practice to access global variables
>   from inside functions, and even worse practice to modify them. This
>   makes it difficult to arrange our program into logically encapsulated
>   parts which do not affect each other in unexpected ways. If a function
>   needs to access some external value, we should pass the value into the
>   function as a parameter. If the function is a method of an object, it
>   is sometimes appropriate to make the value an attribute of the same
>   object

Answer (score 0):

Using global should be avoided if possible. Although using `global` will solve it, it would be wiser to avoid it.

If `program()` would have returned if it succeeds, that would have been helpful.

### For example:

```
def program():
    name=input("What is your name? ")
    country=input("What is your country? ")

    runagain=input("Would you like to run again? Enter no or yes: ")
    if runagain=="no":
        print("Thank You")
        return False
    else:
        print("Rerun")
        return True

while program():
    pass
```